# Facebook phone Messenger app vs. Facebook website Messenger time stamps

Tags: facebook-messenger

I was curious about a Facebook Messenger timestamp disparity that's been coming up. On my phone, the Facebook Messenger app says someone is "active now" whereas on the desktop website it says they were active 1, 2, 3 min ago. When I refresh the web page, it resets to 1min if the phone app still shows active now. What would cause this disparity?

Answer (score -2):

possibly the lag time between when each device is updated.